# awt eventqueue 0- null pointer exception

Tags: error-handling

I'm trying to write a few methods for a class that I'm taking. When I run this method below, using my own personal testing scenarios, it's perfectly fine. But when I try to run the program with my professor's code via the driver class, I get AWT event queue-0. Please help! Thanks.

public Card getCardAt(int position) {

```
    int valueCard=0, suitCard=0;
    Card returnCard;

    if (position>newNumberCards){
        throw new RuntimeException("Invalid position number.");
    }

    valueCard = cards[position].getValue();
    suitCard = cards[position].getSuit();
    returnCard = new Card(valueCard, suitCard);

    return returnCard;
}
```

The problem is with the line:  valueCard = cards[position].getValue();

Thanks.

BTW cards is Card[].